# Read .p12 file with obj-c code

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was trying to read `.p12` file with the following code. It works.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"abc" ofType:@"p12"];
NSData *ABCdata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

> path : /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/xxx/Documents/abc.p12

But if I try to  read 1 file from Email Attachment in Email App, the response is null. I got this path from Share Extension.

```
NSData *ABCdata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pathFromEmail];
```

> pathFromEmail :
>   file:///var/mobile/Library/Mail/IMAP-xxx@gmail.com@imap.gmail.com/INBOX.imapmbox/Attachments/508/2/abc.p12

I searched in google and read documents from apple but can't find any solution for it :( . Maybe my app doesn't have permission to read that file ?

Comment: Try to use dataWithContentsOfFile:options:error: and pass an NSError ** to the second argument. The NSError should have more info about what is failing. 

NSError *error;

NSData *ABCdata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pathFromEmail options:0 error:&error];

Comment: I sloved it :D i just read .p12 file from Share Extension and save it to NSUserdefault then load it when i stay in my app at [viewDidLoad]

Comment: @CôngNguyễn Hi I am facing the same problem can u please share your code how you did this using Share Extention? Thanks in advance.